# Cannot import custom module from same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

This issue seems to be very stupid but I am stuck here.It might be addressed before but I dont know what my exact problem is.
I have 2 python files in same folder : `gui.py` and `parser.py`. In `parser.py` file I have a function called `parseFiles`.

[image: screenshot of file layout]

In `gui.py` I am importing `parse.py` like this:

```
import parser
from parser import parseFiles
```

but I get an error while debugging:

[image: screenshot of exception being displayed]

What trick am I missing here?

Comment: parser is a builtin package. change the file name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import module with name same as built-in module in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602023/import-module-with-name-same-as-built-in-module-in-python-3)

Comment: @SmartManoj Still the local module should have precedence over the standard lib module.

Comment: How are you running gui.py?

Comment: @KlausD.: Not with built-in modules. Some stdlib modules are compiled directly into the Python executable itself, and the import system prioritizes those over modules that come from external files. You can see the names of your Python interpreter's built-in modules in [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names).

Comment: @SmartManoj : changing the filename solved my problem. i was indeed importing the bulitin package.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I am debugging the gui.py in Visual Code.

Comment: @user2357112 That's true, but `parser` is not in there. Checked 2.7 and 3.6.

Comment: if your parser module is directory check in directory exist __init__.py file **Or** parser is file,you must be have parser.py in similar path with gui.py file **Or** parseFiles module not exist in parser module check it.

Comment: @KlausD.: It is on the Python 2.7.15 install I just checked, but not on the 3.6.1 or 3.7.0 (online) interpreters I checked.

Comment: @KlausD.: After digging some more, it looks like `parser` is only built-in on Windows.

Comment: @user2357112 Interesting, there seem to be different modules built-in on the same Python version but (maybe) on a different installation. Something that should be kept in mind.